# How do I choose a video from UIImagePickerController on iPhone 3G?

Tags: iphone, xcode, video, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

On my iPhone 3G I have a couple videos saved from emails and some apps i recored with and every time I try and open the UIImagePickerController it doesn't show the videos for me to choose. How do I get the UIImagePickerController to include videos and not just pictures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, not on the iPhone 3G. For reasons only known to the gods at Apple, almost all video functionality is disabled on the 3G though it can support it perfectly fine.

Comment: But what is the reason for it? The photos app in iPhone 2G/3G does show videos and play them, what is wrong with UIImagePickerController?